# Conditional mean of Gaussian RV given its absolute value is greater than a constant.

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, is there a closed form expression for
$\mathbb{E}(X \mid |X|>A)$?

Thanks in advance!

Intuitively, I think it is zero given we are removing mass around 0 symmetrically, but haven't managed to prove it.

Comment: Isn't it still zero by symmetry?

Comment: Yeah forgot to add that, just edited. I think it's zero but how would you go on proving it?

Comment: By definition $\mathbf{E}(X \mid A) = \frac{1}{\mathbf{P}(A)} \int_A x f_X(x) dx.$ (If you write this down with your own variate, you will reach an odd function over a the region $J \cup -J,$ for some interval $J.$)